# Event.target.id returns empty string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I have a problem with returning an `id` value (defined in the `key` attribute) of the image when using `event.target`.

```
function imageClicked(event) {
    console.log(event.target.key);
    setClicked(event.target.key);
    shuffle(GameData);
    if (clicked.includes(event.target.key) === false) {
      setScore(score + 1);
      setClicked([...clicked, event.target.key]);
    } else {
      setScore(0);
      setClicked([]);
    }
  }

...

 <Display onClick={imageClicked} items={GameData} />
```

And component fragment:

```
<div className="display">
      <img
        src={props.image}
        alt={props.name}
        key={props.id}
        onClick={props.onClick}
      />
      <p>{props.name}</p>
    </div>
```

However when I am using an `alt` attribute of the image the app works as intended. But I want to change it anyway as I creacted ids for all images and they are currently unused.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/memo-game-3d09le) to the full app (using `alt` attribute) in CodeSandbox.

Comment: `event.target.key` -> `event.target[key]`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to be working.